# Instance metaclass changes leaking from instance to instance?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two junit unit tests, one that tests success of a function, and another that tests failure recovery code when an exception occurs.

The CUT (Class Under Test) instance is instantiated in the setUp method.

In the failure test case's preamble, i override one of the cut's methods to throw an excetion, by overriding the method in the instance's metaclass:

```
cut.metaClass.internalWork ={throw new RuntimeException('Failing')}
```

As I understood metaprogramming of an Object (not its static class), when you instantiate a new Object, the metaClass of this new Object is not affected by any metaprogramming you did on the old instance, but that's what I am observing, because I see when executing my success scenario, that the Runtime Exception that is set up in the cut instance that was used for the failure test case, is actually thrown.

If you need more details plea&se let me know, I just want to make sure that I am not making a fundamental theoretical mistake.

Thanks.

**Update**

This is to illustrate how my test case should work:

```
class Cut {
    int fn() {
        internalWork()
        1
    }

    void internalWork() {
        println "Doin work"
    }
}

class WtfTests extends TestSupport {
    @Override
    protected void setUp() {
        println "creating new MS instance"
        cut = new Cut()
    }

    void testSuccess() {
        println "testSuccess"
        cut.fn()
    }

    void testFailure() {
        println "testFailure"
        cut.metaClass.internalWork={->
            println "Won't do work"
            throw new RuntimeException('Failing')
        }
        assert 'Failing'==shouldFail(RuntimeException) {
            cut.fn()
        }
    }
}
```

And this pretty much works as expected:

> creating new MS instance
>   testFailure
>   Won't do work
>   creating new MS instance
>   testSuccess
>   Doin work

**Update 2**

By the way, by adding

```
registerMetaClass(MyClass)
```

to the setUp method, I solved the issue, but this is only supposed to save the static metaclass, not the instance's metaclass, so now I'm thoroughly confused, because as shown in my example above, this should not matter... ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Changes to an instance's metaClass shouldn't affect other instances of the same class.  I can't reproduce the issue with the code you posted.  There must be something else going on.  Can you post a test case that shows the behavior?

Comment: Hi, the test case i posted indeed does not exhibit the behaviour of my real world test case. I was mostly looking for either a clarification or a confirmation that my understanding is correct. It pprobably is related to some interaction between static class metaprogramming and instance metaprogramming that I am not currently able to pinpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You must to clean CUTs metaclass

### Test

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    def remove = GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.&removeMetaClass
    println "Cleaning CUT"
    remove CUT
    remove CUT1
    remove CUT2
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, if I have class A, and an instance cut of class A. If I manipulate the metaclass of the cut INSTANCE, I should clean up the metaclass of A too (the metaclass of the instance's class)?

Comment: When you're mocking a class instances, which use Class metaClass, you shouldn't use instance metaClass. You can view a little dissertation in: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8567?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I'm not sure how that jira applies to my example at all. I don't use mockFor, and I use groovy 1.6+

Comment: Yes bro but the issue is same. You are mocking a class and your are "metaclassing" an instance from that class. Thus you are combining class metaClass and instance metaClass which can mess up all.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, and very interesting that registerMetaClass stuff. I'm asking me, what is the context which your test is running? is an unit or integration test? CUT is a domain class? I cannot to replicate the error.

Comment: CUT is a grails Service. registerMetaClass is a helper method in GrailsUnitTestCase that saves the metaClass to be able to restore it in tearDown(). It is a unit test. As stated above, i think something is going wrong in my real life scenario, because many test methods are executed, and maybe somewhere I do touch the Class metaclass. I don't know. Anyway, the important thing is that instance metaprogramming works the way I expected it to work, so if you don't mind I will be closing the question.